# Transform mapping in order to create multiple components instead of list

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-tsx, pokeapi

So Hello!, I'm trying for the past two days now to transform my code to showcase a list of Pokémon's names (pokeAPI), I Managed to do that with using .map(), But unfortunately, I need the function to divide the names (and eventually the all Pokémon data) into different components instead of just a list of names, you can find my code on GitHub: https://github.com/MikeyTheProgrammer/PokeAPI


or just look down at the code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
export default function PokeCont() {



  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState<any> ()
  
  const onClick = () => {
    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=6").then((response)=>{
      setPokemons(response.data.results)
      console.log(response.data.results)
 })
  }
   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onClick}>Get pokemon</button>
     {pokemons && pokemons.map((pokemon : any) => (
       <div key={pokemon.name}>
         <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
       </div>
     ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

thank you in advance if u could just explain to me the problem of doing so (dividing into multiple components) and sorry if I'm being ignorant

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the properties and build your components like any other component within the `.map` callback.

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onClick}>Get pokemon</button>
     {pokemons && pokemons.map((pokemon : any) => (
       <div key={pokemon.name}>
         <img src={pokemon.image}
         <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
       </div>
     ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```